# how to order entries by likes of user_id?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm working on some laravel app and I have a table called "entries", I save in this table recommendations of name for a contest. I need to order the entries based on how many like the user has in total.

this is my table:

```
id      user_id     contest_id     name               liked

1       1           1              test.com           true
2       4           1              cool.com           false
3       1           1              code.com           true
4       3           1              tool123.com        false
5       2           1              a23423.com         true
6       3           1              dole.net           true
7       1           1              great.com          false
8       2           1              domain.com         true
9       2           1              gol.com            false
10      2           1              greatcode.com      true
11      2           2              greatco.com        true
12      2           2              greatmap.com       true
```

this is what I have:

```
$entries = ContestEntry::where('contest_id', '=', $contest->id)
->orderBy('liked', 'desc')
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->get();
```

I need to order the entrys by:

a given $contest->id (1st line)
if the entry is liked or not (2nd line)
*entries where the user has more likes (globally, not the current contest)*
and by created_at(3rd line)

Schema:

```
Schema::create('contest_entries', function (Blueprint $table) { 
  $table->increments('id'); 
  $table->integer('user_id');
  $table->integer('contest_id');
  $table->text('name');
  $table->text('comment')->nullable();
  $table->boolean('liked')->default(false);
  $table->boolean('available')->default(true);
  $table->timestamp('checked_at');
  $table->timestamps(); 
});
```

output of "show create table contest_entries":

```
CREATE TABLE `contest_entries` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `contest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `comment` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 `liked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `checked_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

what I need is the table as bellow:

```
id      user_id     contest_id     name               liked

5       2           1              a23423.com         true
8       2           1              domain.com         true
9       2           1              gol.com            false
10      2           1              greatcode.com      true
1       1           1              test.com           true
3       1           1              code.com           true
7       1           1              great.com          false
4       3           1              tool123.com        false
6       3           1              dole.net           true
2       4           1              cool.com           false
```

as you can see it shows only data from contest_id 1, user_id 2 has 5 liked = true in all contests thats why its entrys are 1st, user_id 1 has 2 liked = true thats why its entrys ar 2nd.. and go on...

Comment: What is your table schema?

Comment: Please add the sql output of  `show create table contest_entries`.

Comment: You don't seem to have `created_at` field. So how do you expect to order by that?

Comment: laravel adds the created_at field when you adds $table->timestamps();  in the Schema.

Comment: "user_id 2 has 5 liked = true" -- I see only 3??  (ids 5,8,10).  Please clarify.

Comment: yes, it has 5 likes (in the whole table) ids: 5,8,10,11,12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research what I did at the end was create a new scope in ContestEntry model and combine 2 querys as bellow:

```
public function scopeOrderByLikes($query){

    $order = ContestEntry::select('user_id', \DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderByDesc('total')
    ->pluck('user_id');

    return $query->orderBy('user_id',$order);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help to get ordered the list of users by like, in a specific contest.

```
$entries = DB::table('contest_entries')
     ->where('contest_id', '=', $contest->id)
     ->where('liked',true)
     ->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
     ->groupBy('user_id')
     ->orderByDesc('total')
     ->get();
```

Comment: I 'm getting this error with that query: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/AccountController.php on line 66 and at least 1 expected

Comment: thanks for your answer. but this not what I need. what I need is the same table with all entries and its data of a desired contest_id ordered by users_id (that have more liked =  true globally in the same table)

Comment: `Collection {#281 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#277 ▼
      +"user_id": 2
      +"total": 3
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: I mean, the result that you expect (same table with all entries and its data....).

Comment: I just got it. Actually you have the order with the code. Now you have to left join original data with this result, for having what you expect.